# Construct a string from a portion of a char array in C++

Tags: c++, string, arrays, wstring

I've a very big wchar_t array. I'd like to construct a wstring from a portion of this wchar_t array, for example between i and j.

I don't want to turn the big char array into a wstring, and then to take a substring.

How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the iterator pair constructor:

```
std::wstring str(arr + i, arr + j + 1); //need one past the end
```

In this case the addition works because pointers are random-access iterators. For a generic form that works when the iterator does not support `operator+`, use `std::next(arr, i)` and `std::next(arr, j + 1)`. `std::begin` can be used in place of `arr` if worrying about generics as well, as it works on both arrays and standard containers.